# Win32 Dialog closing on startup

Tags: debugging, winapi, directx, dialog

I recently asked a question here about a dialog problem I had, but i discovered that the problem lies in such a different area i intentionally thought that I will rephrase my question here.

The problem is that I've been working on a DirectX10 game engine. When the engine inits there should pop up a dialog box which gives the user the possibility to choose settings. To develop this i created a separate solution (visual studio 2008) where i made the dialog resource and the proc function. I tested it there with a small winmain function and it works perfect.

Then I copied the resource and all the code to my main engine and fired it up. The only thing that happens is that the dialog pops up very shortly and it immediately closes without even waiting for user input. Also the MessageBox function does the same thing. I went through every step, but I'm really stuck.

Could any of you please look at the code for me and see if you can find what the `*`**bleep**`*` is going on?

---

There are three different folders in the zip. VKRenderer is the rending part of the engine where the VKD3D10 is a directX10 implementation of the in VKRenderer defined RenderDevice. In the VKRenderer solution also all the exported functions get exported from VKD3D10. VKD3D10 builds to a dll and VKRenderer to a .lib. Then there is StartupTest which uses the builds to try and start up the engine. The SettingsDialogTest is where i created the settings dialog and all the resources. There you can also find the working version of the settings dialog.

The ZIP file can be downloaded [here](https://secure.storegate.se/user/share.aspx?id=88943fff-e610-4991-a161-61f69125a81b). (The engine is still under development, so be kind with you comments :P ) THANKS A TON IN ADVANCE

pass = HELP

Comment: OMG "hell" is such an offensive word.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, try changing:

```
INT_PTR i = DialogBoxParam(hinst, L"IDD_SETTINGS", hwnd, DlgProcWrapper,(LPARAM) this );
```

to

```
INT_PTR i = DialogBoxParam(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_SETTINGS ), hwnd, DlgProcWrapper,(LPARAM) this );
```

Comment: The former is correct. IDD_SETTINGS is not #defined as a numeric ID, so is treated as a string by the resource compiler.

Comment: Fair enough ... didn't notice that/